# Number to binary

Tags: python, algorithm

Aside from using f-string formatting in python to get a binary string from a number, such as:

```
>>> "{0:>08b}".format(i)
'00001100'
```

What would be the simplest functional/algorithmic way to get the binary representation of a number? For example, what I'm using now is:

```
def number_to_binary(number, s=''):
    while (number):
        s = str(number % 2) + s
        number = number >> 1
    return s
```

Comment: `bin(number)`? You might need to cut off the `0b`.

Comment: `bin(100).replace("0b","")`